# Same width for child elements of flex items

Tags: html, css, html-table, flexbox

I'm trying to figure out a way to recreate a `colspan` using flexbox.

Here a simple example of what I'm trying to achieve: https://jsfiddle.net/4b63b1ze/

```
<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">azerty</td>
        <td colspan="2">azerty</td>
        <td rowspan="2">azerty</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>azerty</td>
        <td>azerty</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/pudxj9sy/

**html:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">azerty</div>
    <div class="item">
        azerty
        <div class="item">azerty</div>
        <div class="item">azerty</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">azerty</div>
    <div class="item">azerty</div>
</div>
```

**style:**

```
.container {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: flex;
}

.item {
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: 0;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

So in theory I have to set the `flex-grow` of the second item to 2. But as the content is dynamically added I don't want to rely on adding style attributes through js/jQuery.

Is there a possibility through css only?

Comment: Currently I do not have time to create what you want, but you can check the `flex-direction` and `order` keywords.

Comment: Not without restructuring the html **and** using `flex-grow:2` to set the width of the middle column. If you want column effects, you have to use column properties,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use nested flexboxes.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">azerty</div>
    <div class="item">
           <div class="item2">azerty</div>
           <div class="container-inner2">
              <div class="item3">azerty</div>
              <div class="item3">azerty</div>
           </div>    
    </div>
    <div class="item">azerty</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    display: flex; /* primary flex container */
    height: 100px; /* for demo purposes */
    border: 1px solid red; /* for demo purposes */
}

.item {
    display: flex; /* flex items declared flex containers, as well */
    justify-content: center; /* center-align flex items (horizontally, in this case) */
    flex: 1; /* flex items take up all available space */
    border: 1px solid gray; /* for demo purposes */
    margin: 2px;  /* for demo purposes */
}

.item:nth-child(2) { 
    flex-direction: column; /* middle item changes direction from row */
    flex-grow: 2; /* middle column gets 2x available space than siblings */
    text-align: center; /* one less nested flexbox (.item2) */
    border: none;  /* remove redundant border */
    margin: 0; /* remove redundant margin */
}

.item2 {
    flex: 1; /* take all available space */
    border: 1px solid gray;
    margin: 2px;
}

.container-inner2 {
    display: flex; /* nested flexbox; flex-direction back to row (by default) */
    flex: 1;  /* take all available space */
}
.item3 {
    flex: 1; /* available space distributed evenly among flex items */
    border: 1px solid gray;
    margin: 2px;
  }
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/pudxj9sy/5/

Comment: Sorry for the late acceptance. It helped me alot, thanks.